# Pink overlay on all RAW files

Tags: xubuntu, shotwell, photography

I am having trouble with viewing RAW files of the type CR2 taken with my Canon EOS 6D camera.

The images show up in normal colors first, then after ~1 second gets a pink overlay added. This happens in all software, Shotwell, Gimp, Darktable etc.

The problem has happened after I did a clean reinstall of Xubuntu. I did not have this problem before reinstalling.

Anyone got an idea?

Example

[image]

Comment: All of these programs rely on libraw for processing RAW files.  Have you tried reinstalling that package?

Comment: I had this problem in 12.04. I no longer have it after upgrading to 13.04.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [LibRaw](http://www.libraw.org/), the library Shotwell relies upon for RAW processing.  LibRaw is based on [dcraw](http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/).

We've seen this problem pop up on various cameras over the years.  The problem is usually solved in dcraw at some point, at which point the code migrates to LibRaw, where it's eventually available to Shotwell.  It may be that dcraw / LibRaw still doesn't process your camera's images correctly; it just depends when the authors fix these problems.

What to do?  First, I recommend upgrading to the newest version of Shotwell and LibRaw if possible.  I don't know what version of Xubuntu you're using, so I don't know if that requires upgrading your operating system.  You can find the latest version of Shotwell at Yorba's PPA: https://launchpad.net/~yorba/+archive/ppa  Even if your version of Xubuntu has an old copy, you may be able to upgrade to the latest (0.14.1) through our PPA.

Second, if that doesn't work or you can't upgrade easily, you should try changing the RAW Developer to **Camera** in Shotwell.  This is available by selecting the photo and choosing **Photos -> Developer -> Camera**.  If you see this problem with all your RAW photos, I suggest changing the default RAW Developer to Camera in **Edit -> Preferences**.

The Camera Developer uses the RAW file's built-in JPEG file (or paired RAW+JPEG if that's the case).  This JPEG is created by the camera itself and shouldn't have discoloration issues.  You can probably try the second step right now and see if you get the right results; either way, I recommend upgrading if at all possible.

**NOTE**: I didn't notice until I posted the above that you're using the Shotwell Photo Viewer (i.e. you're double-clicking on the RAW file in Nautilus).  The Camera Developer is only available in Shotwell's library mode, that is, you run Shotwell and import the photos into your library.