# Darktable shows RAW (.NEF) in pink in darkroom

Tags: photography, photo-editing, darktable

I just installed Darktable, in lighttable mode my raw files are shown proper but in darkroom it shows pinkish.

[image]

P.S. [Pink overlay on all RAW files](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327446/pink-overlay-on-all-raw-files) did not solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem got solved by updating the Darktable to 1.6. As there Darktable below 1.6 does not supports D5300 Camera.